# How can i stop the timer outside. like if i click a button outside of countdowntimer method?

Tags: android, countdowntimer

how can i stop countdown timer, if i click buttonstop outside of this method?
im making game which had a timer, when i click the button submit and if the answer identify that the answer is correct the timer will stop.

please help me guys. i need it to my project.

```
       public void timer1(){
    timer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer);

    final CountDownTimer Counter2 = new CountDownTimer(120000 , 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timer.setText( formatTime(millisUntilFinished));
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            timer.setText("GAME OVER");

        }
        };


        Context mcontext=this; 

    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
          mcontext);

  alert.setTitle("LEVEL 1");
  alert.setPositiveButton("Start",
          new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                   int which) {
                  dialog.cancel();
                  Counter2.start();

                  question();
              }
          });
      alert.show();
}
public void timer2(){
    timer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.timer);

    final CountDownTimer Counter1 = new CountDownTimer(120000 , 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            timer.setText( formatTime(millisUntilFinished));
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            timer.setText("GAME OVER");

        }
        };


        Context mcontext=this; 

    final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(
          mcontext);

  alert.setTitle("CORRECT");
  alert.setPositiveButton("OK",
          new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

              @Override
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                      int which) {
                  dialog.cancel();
                  Counter1.start();

                  question();
              }
          });
      alert.show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

use `Counter2.cancel` inside your button onclick...

Answer (score 1):

```
timer.cancel();
```

above code way to stop your timer.

Comment: on ur onclick button or where u want to stop ur timer.